# Find Regex expression to match specefic word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression to match exact word and replace it with another. But the expression I have used, replace even word that start with specific character like @.

Here's my code :

```
static public string ReplaceWholeWord(this string original, string wordToFind, string replacement, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None){
       string pattern = String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", wordToFind);
       string ret = Regex.Replace(original, pattern, replacement, regexOptions);
       return ret;
}
```

Here's the result :

```
var input = "if(@test is not null)";
input.ReplaceWholeWord("test", "x");
```

> Result : if(@x is not null)

For the moment, I only need to avoid matching the words that have a `@` character in front of them.

Comment: There is a word boundary between `@` and `t`. Try `@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)"` if you want to only replace a word enclosed with whitespaces. What do you consider word boundaries in this case? Or do you want to only avoid matching after `@`? Then use `@"\b(?<!@){0}\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I suppose the `test` should be replaced in `if(test ...)`, so `(?<!\S)...` would fail to match. We need to clarify the requirements and explicitly state what chars are considered to be "part of a word" and what characters are not.

Comment: @MoezRebai, would you please explicitly state what chars are considered to be "part of a word" and what characters are not.

Comment: for the moment I only need to discard the @ character, and it seems to work with @WiktorStribiżew suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want to avoid matching whole words that are immediately preceded with a `@` symbol, you just need to add a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"\b(?<!@){0}\b"
    ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3c!%40%29test%5cb&i=if%28%40test+is+not+null%29%0d%0aif%28test+is+null%29).

The regex will now match a word boundary position first, then it will check the previous char, and if it is a `@` the whole match will be failed. Only if the preceding char is not `@`, the `test` with a trailing word boundary will get matched.

Comment: I like that second solution, kind of working as charm thanks.

Comment: Note you may adjust it further: if you need to also avoid matching words that are preceded with `#`, put the unwanted chars into a character class and use `@"\b(?<![@#]){0}\b"`. If you plan to avoid matching words that have some *sequence* of chars before, use an alternation, e.g. `@"\b(?<![@#]|==\s*){0}\b"` (i.e. words not preceded with `==` and 0+ whitespaces).